# C# inheritance and polymorphism

Tags: c#

I have these 2 class in my web service:

```
[DataContract]
public class AllFile
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public virtual string base64Data { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class UploadFile : AllFile
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string data;

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public override string base64Data { get { return data; } set { data = value; } }

}

ServiceReference.UploadFile obj = new ServiceReference.UploadFile();
obj.base64Data = "something";
AllFile file = (UploadFile)obj;
```

However, it tells me that file.base64Data is null. Why?
I thought I overrided the sub class already.

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base class `AllFile` does not contain a `data`-member, so you can't access it! You declared your `virtual` member as a property and in your sub-class you provide a new member that does not exist in your base-class. 
So don't mark your member as virtual in your base-class

```
[DataContract]
public class AllFile
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string base64Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that using the override keyword will force my file object to use the subclass's property instead of the base class..am I wrong? Thats the reason why I put virtual in the parent class properties.

Comment: No you are right. Specifying a property as`virtual` is not very useful in your case. Either have the private member in the base class or use virtual methods to impose a behavior on your subclasses.

Comment: If my subclass is overriding the base class property, wouldn't my file.base64Data be accessing the field "data" in the sub class? How come I need a field in the parent class too? Sorry can you help me understand?

Comment: I think I kind of understand what you're trying to say. I am doing things that are unnecessary because by inheriting the base class I already get those properties. The thing I don't understand now is why overriding the base class property won't work? Why is file.base64Data returning null?

Comment: Ahh, I've fixed the error. It wasn't a inheritance / polymorphism error. It has been a deserialization error all along with my web service. I just had to add the known types as described here into my base class to get it working. Thank you for all the explanations!

If it helps anyone, this is what I did.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085438/adding-knowntype-attribute-causes-unknown-error
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Why would you override the property at the first place. You are breaking the OOP concepts. You have a public field 'data' and you get it's value from the base64Data string. If you are going to do that at least make the 'data' private. After that making the value64Data just a normal property in your base class and leaving it with simple {get;set;} is pretty much enought for your derived class to have it too and makes all that setting pointless and it this case non-working.

```
DataContract]
public class AllFile
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string base64Data { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class UploadFile : AllFile
{

}

ServiceReference.UploadFile obj = new ServiceReference.UploadFile();
obj.base64Data = "something";
AllFile file = (UploadFile)obj;
```

if we follow the OOP concepts this should be your code and it should work just fine.

And if we follow the OOP concepts even more this should be your code :

```
[DataContract]
public class AllFile
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string base64Data { get; protected set; }
    public virtual void SetBase64Data(string data)
    {
        this.base64Data = data;
    }
}
[DataContract]
public class UploadFile : AllFile
{

}

ServiceReference.UploadFile obj = new ServiceReference.UploadFile();
obj.SetBase64Data("data");
AllFile file = (UploadFile)obj;
```

Comment: AH, I did forget to make my field private. I have a few file subclass and I want each property in the subclass to override the original. However, my understanding is that using the override keyword will force my file object to use the subclass's property instead of the base class..am I wrong? Thats the reason why I overrided the subclass property.